# Does Alamofire request actually run in the background thread?

Tags: swift, alamofire, background-process, alamofire-request

I'm using Alamofire for the first time and I have a question. I searched and found a similar post on stackoverflow but the answers are very confusing, even the documentation is confusing. Alamofire is pretty convenient because I don't have to create session and tasks. However, I have used DispatchQueue before and I know for it runs the tasks in background thread and update UI on main thread but I don't know if Alamofire does the same. Please reply if you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Alamofire request actually run in the background thread

Yes,Alamofire tasks run in a background thread and dispatch their callbacks in main thread